# Spark Structured Streaming - Realtime aggregation for the last X hour(s) data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, real-time-data

I'm new to spark and I'm using spark structured streaming to read streams of data from Kafka in scala language.

I want to aggregate the last X hours of data using Apache Spark, and (if possible) write only the updates to the destination,

So let's say I want the minimum price for customer `ID1` in the last 1 hours, so if I had the following events:

```
Events Data:
+------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+
|event_time                                |customer                 |price    |
+------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+
| 2021-03-09 11:00:00                      |ID1                      |2000     |
| 2021-03-09 11:28:00                      |ID1                      |1500     |
| 2021-03-09 15:20:00                      |ID1                      |2500     |
+------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+
at 2021-03-09 11:00:00 desired output (data between 10:00:00 and 11:00:00) :
+-------------------------+------------+
|customer                 |min_price   |
+-------------------------+------------+
|ID1                      |2000        |
+-------------------------+------------+
at 2021-03-09 11:28:00 desired output (data between 10:28:00 and 11:28:00):
+-------------------------+------------+
|customer                 |min_price   |
+-------------------------+------------+
|ID1                      |1500        |
+-------------------------+------------+
at 2021-03-09 15:20:00 desired output (data between 14:20:00 and 15:20:00):
+-------------------------+------------+
|customer                 |min_price   |
+-------------------------+------------+
|ID1                      |2500        |
+-------------------------+------------+
```

instead, Kafka is keep outputting 1500
I tried to filter the input stream to last 1 hour
I tried to use a sliding window but I'm getting too many windows and I only need the last window  that ends with the last event_time.

```
val df = spark.readStream
              .format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", brokers)
              .option("subscribe", topics)
              .option("startingOffsets", "latest").load()

val ds1 = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)").as[(String, String)]
// some more transformation ds1 => data

// this is filtering try

filteredData = data.filter($"event_time" > (current_timestamp() - expr("INTERVAL 1 hours")))
results = filteredData.groupBy($"customer").agg(min("price").alias("min_price"))

//this is sliding window
results = filteredData.groupBy(window($"event_time", "1 hours", "5 minutes"),$"customer")
                      .agg(min("price").alias("min_price"))
```

for testing purposes, I'm writing to console

is this feasible in spark structured streaming?